# aggregate through across multiple columns in R

Tags: r

Suppose I have a `data.frame` called `df`

```
x y z
1 2 3
2 3 4
3 4 5
1 3 4
2 4 5
```

I want to

1. group the data by `x`
2. for each sub `data.frame`, do `func(df$y, df$z)`

How to do this without a loop?

Comment: Look into the `aggregate` function, the `plyr` package, the `group_by` function in the `dplyr` package, and/or the use of the `.SD` object in the `data.table` package.

Comment: @ssdecontrol, I tried, but the problem is that `aggregate` or `apply` do the aggregation only on one column at a time, i.e., the aggregating function has the signature `fun(x)` where `x` is a atomic vector or list.

Comment: that isn't true in either case.

Comment: @ssdecontrol Could you please show me a simple code?  That would be a great help.  I'm a newbie to R and I've been doing this for hours.

Comment: sorry, I didn't realize what you meant by "only one column". I'm writing an answer anyway

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use regular `plyr` for this:

```
library(plyr)
dlply(df, .(x), function(sub_df) func(sub_df$y, sub_df$z))
# or ddply or daply as desired
```

or `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(x) %>% summarize(func(y, z))
```

or `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
df <- as.data.table(df)
df[, func(y, z), by = x]
```

Comment: This helps!  I just tried `by` function with success.  BTW, where is the doc for `.SD`?  in `data.table` manual?

Comment: It's in `?data.table`, in the description of the `by` argument.

Comment: The second one doesn't actually work.  My `x, y, z` are all floating point numbers

Comment: @gongzhitaao did you try it? It works fine on the `iris` data: `iris %>% group_by(Sepal.Length) %>% summarize(mean(c(Sepal.Width, Petal.Width)))`

Comment: Still, it seems the first one works.  I need to dive into the other two.  Thanks.

Comment: It seems that the the other two run into problem when `func` returns a function.

Comment: +1. You can just pass `y, z`. `df[, func(y,z), by=x]`.

Comment: @Arun thanks, I'm never sure when `.SD` is necessary.

Comment: @ssdecontrol, most common use is when you've too many columns to compute some operation on.. ex: `DT[, lapply(.SD, fun), by=.]`. Another use is if you'd want to perform a join in `j` on each group.. `setkey(DT, x); DT[, .SD[J(.), ...], by=y]` - here you group by `y` and join on each group on `x` column...

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for this?

```
# assume df is your data frame
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(x) %>% do(...)
```

Comment: Both solved my problem.  Thanks!  But I could only accept one answer.  Gave credit to the other one with lower rep :P  Thank you so much